# port-binding failures for subethasmtp email server in Openshift environment

Tags: openshift

I have an application which uses subethasmtp library to receive inbound emails. I have tested my application (a listener) on my laptop by binding the （subethasmtp) email server to port 25. It worked fine.

When I built my application on Openshift, I received the following exception:

ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) JBWEB000287: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.SandRiver.InvoiceMailServer.InvoiceListener: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Permission denied

I also tried to bind to a port > 20000, but received the same error message.

May someone help me?

Best Regards,

John Zhu

Answer (score 0):

You can not bind to port 25, that requires root access.  You should try ports between 15000 and 20000, and see if that works, it should.  Also, those ports will not be able to be accessed from outside of your gear, so unless you are trying to just use that mail server for something on your gear, it is not going to work correctly (accept/send email from an outside source)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I saw previous notes on the forum regarding setting port forwarding in Openshift environment, that would require a successful port binding as prerequisite. Is there any openshift native way of receiving external emails?

Comment: Just tried to bind it to 16000, but got the same error message.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?